# JMeter testing for the url which contains @ as path param

Tags: api, http, jmeter, character-encoding, special-characters

I have REST API which takes the username as a path parameter like this - app/users/{username}.
As per the business requirement, the username can be an email address as well.
Application is developed and we can test using postman, curl etc., by encoding the URL. But when we use JMeter to test the same API,
We are not able to send the encoded URL using JMeter. To demonstrate the problem, I created a webhook site(https://webhook.site/3c84998f-ecbb-4cee-a1e1-7c7ae059a209/testjmeter%40jmeter)
and requested as below.

"GET [https://webhook.site/3c84998f-ecbb-4cee-a1e1-7c7ae059a209/testjmeter%40jmeter"](https://webhook.site/3c84998f-ecbb-4cee-a1e1-7c7ae059a209/testjmeter%40jmeter%22)

This resulted in a webhook as below

"https://webhook.site/3c84998f-ecbb-4cee-a1e1-7c7ae059a209/testjmeter@jmeter"

But we want the output like below which we could accomplish by postman or curl.

curl --location --request GET 'https://webhook.site/3c84998f-ecbb-4cee-a1e1-7c7ae059a209/testjmeter%40jmeter'

Please help how I need to prepare my JMeter script which produce the same output as above (in curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/)

Not sure what does your "webhook" do, however in a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) request paths are exactly the same for curl and JMeter and no `%40` doesn't get decoded into `@`

[image]

If you're capable of sending your request successfully via curl or postman you should be able to record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) - this way you will get appropriate JMeter configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I was using JMeter 5.1.1. Once I used  JMeter 5.4 the issue is resolved.